# how to use 2 constructor in MVVM in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oop, mvvm

I want to use a different constructor in a WPF MVVM project. First one is used in MDI form. But second constructor usage is over another form which have been sending a parameter to second one. How can I use it?

```
public MyModelView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tlb.SelectVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

public MyModelView(MyViewModel test)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = test;
    tlb.SelectVisibility = test.Visibility;
}
```

I have two constructors. But I have a datacontext in xaml side. The error is

`Xaml parse exception: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'XYZ.AP.UI.ViewModel.MyViewModel' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '6'.`

```
<Windows:TransactionWindow.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MyViewModel />
</Windows:TransactionWindow.DataContext>
```

Comment: plz provide the constructors of the viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a parameterized constructor from XAML. You could get around this restriction by setting the window's `DataContext` in code when you create the window.

But it looks like you've tried to set the `DataContext` to be `MyViewModel` not `MyModelView`. This is probably the source of your exception.

As an aside, what's with the 'ModelView' and 'ViewModel' names? These seem confusingly similar... and it's not what the letters MVVM stand for.